# How does rsync behave for concurrent file access?

Tags: concurrency, locking, rsync

I'm using rsync to run backups of my machine twice a day and the ten to fifteen minutes when it searches my files for modifications, slowing down everything considerably, start getting on my nerves.

Now I'd like to use the inotify interface of my kernel (I'm running Linux) to write a small background app that collects notifications about modified files and adds their pathnames to a list which is then processed regularly by a call to rsync.

Now, because this process by definition always works on files I've just been - and might still be - working on, I'm wondering whether I'll get loads of corrupted / partially updated files in my backup as rsync copies the files while I'm writing to them.

I couldn't find anyhing in the manpage and was yet unsuccessful in googling for the answer. I could go read the source, but that might take quite a while. Anybody know how concurrent file access is handled inside rsync?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not handled at all: rsync opens the file, reads as much as it can and copies that over.

So it depends how your applications handle this: Do they rewrite the file (not creating a new one) or do they create a temp file and rename that when all data has been written (as they should).

In the first case, there is little you can do: If two processes access the same data without any kind of synchronization, the result will be a mess. What you could do is defer the rsync for N minutes, assuming that the writing process will eventually finish before that. Reschedule the file if it is changes again within this time limit.

In the second case, you must tell rsync to ignore temp files (*.tmp, *~, etc).

Answer (score 2):

It isn't handled in any way. If it is a problem, you can use e.g. LVM snapshots, and take the backup from the snapshot. That won't in itself guarantee that the files will be in a usable state, but it does guarantee that, as the name implies, it's a snapshot at a specific time.

Note that this doesn't have anything to do with whether you're letting rsync handle the change detection itself or if you use your own app. Your app, or rsync itself, just produces a list of files that have been changed, and then for each file, the rsync binary diff algorithm is run. The problem is if the file is changed while the rsync algorithm runs, not when producing the file list.